# Dictionary as CMS or wiki

Tags: cms, wiki, dictionary

I have an idea for a kind of online dictionary for a specific area and several languages. It should be filled and revisioned by community or small group of editors.

The software core should also have an API to make app development possible.

Another feature of this dictionary I would like to have, the possibility to download part of the dictionary for two languages, i.e. kind of Spanish-German or English-Russian for offline usage.

The first idea is to setup MediaWiki, but I'm not sure if it's the right choice.

Could you recommend any software or solutions?

Comment: I think that's something you'll have to develop yourself. But, if you want a core system I think mediawiki is really the right choice as it's very extendable. I've seen apps which dramatically extended its functionality.

Comment: Thank you @NadavS. could you send me links to the app you wrote about?

Comment: The app I've seen is in Hebrew... Anyway, it's a hiking map of Israel (very popular app) which all of its places are managed by mediawiki. If you hover over a blue circle and click on the card's title a mediawiki page will open with a custom-formatted entry. The developer actually disabled "freestyle" editing and instead put specific content types like Name, Waypoint, image etc. [Amud Anan](http://amudanan.co.il/)